# Disappearing data in extended QTreeWidgetItem

Tags: python, pyqt5, missing-data, qtreewidget, qtreewidgetitem

**UPDATE: (SOLVED)**

Thanks to ***eyllanesc*** for making me write a working example code of my problem. That made me find the problem. Here is a working code with a fixed problem:

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
import sys
import os

class ExtendedTreeWidgetItem(QTreeWidgetItem):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ExtendedTreeWidgetItem, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.rescueFile = None
        print("created first time")

    def setRescueFile(self, rFile):
        self.rescueFile = rFile
        print("setting rescue file", self.rescueFile, "for item", self.text(0))

    def getRescueFile(self):
        return self.rescueFile

class RescueFile:
    def __init__(self, path):
        self.path = path
        self.ischecked = True

    def isChecked(self):
        return self.ischecked

    def setChecked(self, checked):
        if isinstance(checked, bool):
            self.ischecked = checked
        elif isinstance(checked, Qt.CheckState):
            self.ischecked = True if checked == Qt.Checked else False

    def getPath(self):
        return self.path


class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        windowSize = (800,400)
        screenSize = QDesktopWidget().availableGeometry()
        self.setGeometry(screenSize.width()/2 - windowSize[0]/2, screenSize.height()/2 - windowSize[1]//2, windowSize[0], windowSize[1])
        self.setWindowTitle("TreeTest")



        self.buildGui()

        self.show()

    def buildGui(self):
        wgt = QWidget()
        vlayout = QVBoxLayout()
        vlayout.setAlignment(Qt.AlignTop)
        grid_layout = QGridLayout()

        self.setupTree(grid_layout)

        vlayout.addLayout(grid_layout)
        wgt.setLayout(vlayout)
        self.setCentralWidget(wgt)


    def setupTree(self, grid_layout):
        self.treeWidget = QTreeWidget()
        self.treeWidget.setHeaderLabel("Results")
        self.treeWidget.setColumnCount(1)

        #INSERTING DATA
        topItem = ExtendedTreeWidgetItem()
        topItem.setText(0, "top item")
        topItem.setCheckState(0, Qt.Checked)
        child1 = ExtendedTreeWidgetItem(topItem)
        child1.setText(0, "child 1")
        child1.setCheckState(0, Qt.Checked)
        topItem.addChild(child1)
        deeper_child = ExtendedTreeWidgetItem(child1)
        deeper_child.setText(0, "deeper child 1")
        deeper_child.setCheckState(0, Qt.Checked)
        r_file = RescueFile("/home/user1/Desktop")
        deeper_child.setRescueFile(r_file)
        child1.addChild(deeper_child)

        self.treeWidget.addTopLevelItem(topItem)
        self.treeWidget.expandAll()

        self.treeWidget.itemChanged.connect(self.singleClickTreeWidget)
        grid_layout.addWidget(self.treeWidget, 1, 1, 4, 3)

    def singleClickTreeWidget(self, widgetItem, column):
        parent = widgetItem.parent()
        if parent and parent.checkState(0) == Qt.Unchecked:
            widgetItem.setCheckState(0, Qt.Unchecked)
            return

        checkState = widgetItem.checkState(0)

        widgetItem.setCheckState(0, checkState)
        rescue_file = widgetItem.getRescueFile()
        if rescue_file:
            rescue_file.setChecked(checkState)
            print("rescue file found, path:", rescue_file.getPath(), "checked:", rescue_file.isChecked())

        self.iterateThroughChildren(widgetItem, checkState)

    def iterateThroughChildren(self, item, checkState):
        for i in range(item.childCount()):
            child = item.child(i)
            print("child:", child, ",text:", child.text(0))
            child.setCheckState(0, checkState)
            # HERE WAS THE MISTAKE
            # -- >> rescue_file = item.getRescueFile()  << --
            rescue_file = child.getRescueFile()  # CORRECT CODE!! 
            print("rescue file", rescue_file, "child", child.text(0))
            if rescue_file is not None:
                rescue_file.setChecked(checkState)
            else:
                self.iterateThroughChildren(child, checkState)



def main():
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        app = QApplication(sys.argv)
        window = Window()
        app.exec_()

main()
```

**BEFORE UPDATE:**

I hope I can explain my problem clearly enough.

I trying to create QTreeWidget that uses my extended QTreeWidgetItems in python 3.5.3. Here is my code for the item class:

```
class ExtendedTreeWidgetItem(QTreeWidgetItem):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ExtendedTreeWidgetItem, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.rescueFile = None

    def setRescueFile(self, rFile):
        self.rescueFile = rFile

    def getRescueFile(self):
        return self.rescueFile



class RescueFile:

    def __init__(self, path):
        self.path = path
        self.ischecked = True

    def isChecked(self):
        return self.ischecked

    def setChecked(self, checked):
        if isinstance(checked, bool):
            self.ischecked = checked
        elif isinstance(checked, Qt.CheckState):
            self.ischecked = True if checked == Qt.Checked else False
        print(self.path, self.ischecked)
```

I use this code to implement checking and unchecking the rescue file:

```
****
...
self.treeWidget.itemChanged.connect(self.singleClickTreeWidget)
...
****


def singleClickTreeWidget(self, widgetItem, column):
        parent = widgetItem.parent()
        if parent and parent.checkState(0) == Qt.Unchecked:
            widgetItem.setCheckState(0, Qt.Unchecked)
            return

        checkState = widgetItem.checkState(0)

        widgetItem.setCheckState(0, checkState)
        rescue_file = widgetItem.getRescueFile()
        **# I CAN GET THE RESCUE FILE OBJECT HERE FROM**
        if rescue_file:
            rescue_file.setChecked(checkState)

        self.iterateThroughChildren(widgetItem, checkState)



def iterateThroughChildren(self, item, checkState):
    for i in range(item.childCount()):
        child = item.child(i)
        child.setCheckState(0, checkState)
        **# I CAN'T GET ANY FIND HERE ANYMORE**
        rescue_file = item.getRescueFile()
        if rescue_file:
            rescue_file.setChecked(checkState)
        else:
            self.iterateThroughChildren(child, checkState)
```

What my code does is that it generates a checkable tree like in the picture:
[image: QTreeWidget]

What I'm trying to achieve is that when I deselect/select an item (ExtendedTreeWidgetItem) that has children, all children are also selected/deselected as well as RescueFile objects associated with items. Only files are associated with RescueFile objects. Directories are left with `self.rescueFile = None`

For example if I pressed to deselect 'icons' then magnifier.png should also be deselected as well as RescueFile associated with it. Deselection of a checkboxes works like a charm but RescueFile is not affected (NOT FOUND) if I press on a parent of a file. But it works if I press directly on a file, for example magnifier.png.

I have tried to trace if it is a pointer problem but it seems like all objects point to the objects they are supposed to. I don't understand where does a rescueFile disappear if I am comming to ExtendedTreeWidgetItem recursively through it's parent.

Comment: you could provide a decent [mcve]

Comment: thanks for making me do it eyllanesc. I found my problem and updated the post as solved